# Titanium: Show and Create Contact Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium, contacts, appcelerator

I was trying to export contacts from my application to the native android contacts.

I found the following solution here on this site: [Titanium: How to add Contact in Phone book in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579642/titanium-how-to-add-contact-in-phone-book-in-android).

And it kinda works. The intent gets started. Only problem is, that android does not recognize most of the Extras i put in. So almost every field is blank. It does not matter if I replace contactModel with a simple String, the result is the same.

So i was wondering if the keys are simply wrong, but there seems no proper documentation on appcelerator. Probably something has changed over the past years or I am just missing something. Does anybody know how to do it the right way.

Code Snippet:

```
if (OS_ANDROID) {
    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
        action : 'com.android.contacts.action.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT',
        data : 'mailto:' + contactModel.get('contact_first_name')  + ' ' + contactModel.get('contact_last_name') 
    });

    intent.putExtra('email', contactModel.get('contact_email')); 
    intent.putExtra('email_type', 'Work');
    intent.putExtra('phone', contactModel.get('contact_mobile_number'));
    intent.putExtra('phone_type', 'mobile');
    intent.putExtra('name', contactModel.get('contact_first_name')  + ' ' + contactModel.get('contact_last_name') );
    intent.putExtra('address', addressModel.get('address_street') + ", " + addressModel.get('address_city'));
    intent.putExtra('address_type', 'Work'); 

    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thx in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `putExtra()` also accepts one of the constants `Ti.Android...`. So instead of `email` you would probably have to use `Ti.Android.EXTRA_EMAIL`.

I think you can find quite a lot in the docs, e.g. here:

[EXTRA constant properties in Ti docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android)

[EXTRA constants in Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL)

[Android Intents in Ti docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Intents)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately using constants (which i tried) does not have any effect. Furthermore there are only two constants in Ti.Android (Ti.Android.EXTRA_EMAIL & Ti.Android.PHONE_NUMBER) regarding Contact Intents, but the Contact Activity (Android) is able to contain more information than just those two. What do i do with the address? And so on... :D. But thx for your input.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Actually i can't even find any more contacts-specific constants in the Android docs. If it really does not work with the Titanium SDK, you could think about writing and/or using a Titanium module.